# SQL Query: How to list joined values on the same row

Tags: sql

I've got a table of job listings and a related table which contains the job listing ids and each of the field values in a 'field title' -> 'field value' format.

So to get my listing of jobs, I've JOINED the tables in my SQL Query, but am getting the results on multiple lines because of that.  Let me illustrate.

Query is something like:

```
SELECT list.id, list.activation_date, list_field.value 
  FROM listings AS list
 INNER JOIN listings_fields AS list_field ON list.id = list_field.id
 WHERE list.activation_date > SOME VALUE
   AND list_field.field_id IN ('Title', 'Category')
 ORDER BY list.activation_date DESC, list_field.field_id DESC
```

The result looks like this:

```
51325   2012-07-31  Job Title 1
51325   2012-07-31  Category 1, Category 2
51324   2012-07-31  Job Title 2
51324   2012-07-31  Category 3
51323   2012-07-31  Job Title 3
51323   2012-07-31  Category 1, Category 3
```

I've got all the data I need, it's ordered consistently with title first and category second, but I can't think of how to get the result all in one row.  This must be a common problem with a well-known trick, and I'm sorry I don't know it yet.

Still learning.  If anyone can help, I'd really appreciate it.  :-)

Comment: It is a common scenario, but a job often better handled at the application-level rather than SQL.  What application language are you using?

Comment: Oh, yes, of course.  Everything here is handled by a robust application!  I'm not tinkering with the SQL to set up the jobs application or anything.  I'm actually asking this more out of curiosity.  I was trying to pull some information out of the DB to get system usability info, and realized I didn't know how to accomplish the above.  So, I don't want to balloon out the question unnecessarily. I really was just curious about whether that can be done in an SQL query.  :-)  Any ideas?

Comment: @Boriana So basically you need to Group By ID and then concatenate the string data so it'd become something like

51325 Job Title 1, Caregory 1, Category 2

?

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to use Group By already, but don't see how to do the concatenation, since both the job title and the categories are coming from the 'list_field.value' column from the table I've joined...  When I group, I get that single row, of course, but with only the category listed in the list_field.value column.  Concatenating the column with itself just lists it twice, it doesn't grab the value from the row below.  Does that make any sense?  What am I doing wrong? (Maybe I should provide more info on the tables' structure...)?

Comment: String aggregates is indeed a common task in SQL, take a look at this: http://codecorner.galanter.net/2009/06/25/t-sql-string-aggregate-in-sql-server/ (keep in mind this is TSQL flavor of SQL)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL? DB2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
SELECT list.id, list.activation_date, list_fieldJ.value,list_fieldC.value
 FROM listings AS list
 INNER JOIN listings_fields AS list_fieldJ ON list.id = list_fieldJ.id 
    and List_fieldj = 'Title'
 INNER JOIN listings_fields AS list_fieldC ON list.id = list_fieldC.id 
    and List_fieldC = 'Category'

 WHERE list.activation_date > SOME VALUE
 ORDER BY list.activation_date DESC
```

Basically join once for title and then again for Category. Needless to say it's a pain if you have more than few value types to get out. And the above assumes that a job will always have title and category. Optional ones you'd need an outer join on.